# check a setup file (.exe file) is installed or not in windows programmatically

Tags: registry

**problem statement:**
I have one .exe file say 'abc.exe' and I installed it programmatically using process.Start() in silent mode.
If I go to install this 'abc.exe' file again it should tell me that it has been installed already.

**In detail:** 
As soon as we install an entry will be made in registry. I can able to list uninstallString of  all the installed application from registry programmatically, but wanted to fetch an uninstallString of 'abc.exe' file.

Any help in this is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any particular language?

Comment: Yeah. I am doing this in C# language.